# Javascript passing string parameter - then using setStyle

Tags: javascript, string, parameters, parameter-passing

Current function:

```
function SetPopup() {
    x$('body').setStyle('overflow', 'hidden');
    x$('#divOne').setStyle('height', document.body.offsetHeight + 'px');
    x$('#divOne').setStyle('width', 100 + '%');
    x$('#divOne').setStyle('display', 'block');
}
```

What I would like to do is change this function such that 'divOne' would be read-in as a parameter like this:

```
function SetPopup(string x) {
    x$('body').setStyle('overflow', 'hidden');
    x$('#x').setStyle('height', document.body.offsetHeight + 'px');
    x$('#x').setStyle('width', 100 + '%');
    x$('#x').setStyle('display', 'block');
}
```

But obviously that doesnt work.

What would I need to do to include x where I have optimistically placed it in the bottom function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function SetPopup(elem) {
    x$('body').setStyle('overflow', 'hidden');
    x$('#' + elem).setStyle('height', document.body.offsetHeight + 'px');
    x$('#' + elem).setStyle('width', 100 + '%');
    x$('#' + elem).setStyle('display', 'block');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function SetPopup(x) {
    x$('body').setStyle('overflow', 'hidden');
    x$('#'+x).setStyle('height', document.body.offsetHeight + 'px');
    x$('#'+x).setStyle('width', 100 + '%');
    x$('#'+x).setStyle('display', 'block');
}
```